# How to better control the position of the long equation?

Tags: math-mode, two-column

How to better control the position of the long equation.
I have the following equation, however, the long equation sometimes overlapped with other equation, and sometimes run out of the paper.

The code is as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}

\begin{strip}
\begin{eqnarray}
  A
 &=& \left[ \begin{array}{ccccc}
 x+z.^2+c+v+g.^2 = 2 & & \\
 &  \ddots & & &  \\
& &  x.^2+y+z.^2 = 2 & &   \\
 & & & \ddots &  \\
& & & &   x+y.^2+z^2+g = 2
 \end{array} \right].
\end{eqnarray}
\end{strip}
\end{document}
```

An example is here

[image]

How can I get a result like this?

[image]

Comment: Are you in two column mode?

Comment: yes, in two column moed.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `eqnarray`: you'll get bad spacing. Replace it with one of the `amsmath` environments `align` or `aligned` instead.

I propose two solutions: one full width using the `strip` environment from `cuted` and `equation` since there's nothing to align. The other on two lines and fitting a single column using the `\medmath` command from `nccmath` to make medium-sized formulae (~ 80 % of display style).

I also simplified your code with a `pmatrix` environment in the place of `array` and loaded `mathtools`, an extension of `amsmath` because I needed the `\mathclap` command to get a better-looking large matrix:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
 \begin{align}
  & A = \notag\\
  &\setlength\arraycolsep{1pt} \medmath{\begin{bmatrix}
 x+z.^2+c+v+g.^2 = 2 & & \\
 & \ddots & & & \\
 & & \mathclap{x.^2+y+z.^2 = 2} & & \\
 & & & \ddots & \\
 & & & & x+y.^2+z^2+g = 2
 \end{bmatrix}}
 \end{align}
\lipsum[3] \begin{strip}
 \begin{align}
   A = & \begin{bmatrix}
 x+z.^2+c+v+g.^2 = 2 & & \\
 & \ddots & & & \\
 & & \mathclap{x.^2+y+z.^2 = 2} & & \\
 & & & \ddots & \\
 & & & & x+y.^2+z^2+g = 2
 \end{bmatrix}
 \end{align}
 \end{strip}
\lipsum[4-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, but it still has the problem.

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't fully understand your problem. Could you give some details?

Comment: I copy your code, but the result is still the same as I posted before.

Comment: I guess this is because the result will change with the environment.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand what you want, as you have shown no overlapping of equations.